# intruments6 track uiview retain by class name

Tags: xcode, xcode6, instruments, xcode-instruments

I'm using instruments 6.4 to track an over retained object (`UIView`) and normally I would track this by name. eg use the search field with *"FeaturedView"* and it would pull up all the objects built from that class.

The new instruments does not do that by default. The best I can do is search for *"UIView"* but that leads to a wild goose chase.

How can I watch only the view(s) associated with my custom *"FeaturedView"* class?

*In earlier versions of instruments you could search for 'uiview' and it would list all 13 with their associated class name - in recent versions you get this:*
[image: xcode instruments6 allocations]

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @Daniel Not yet. I looked around for a couple hours the other day and it's rare to find anything about new versions of instruments period. I'm hoping a WWDC video will give me more info.

Comment: I just found a newer [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/97886/instruments-tutorial-with-swift-getting-started) on raywenderlich where the section _Strong Reference Cycles_ mentions that there is a bug in instruments...